# Github Actions: workflow runs but nothing happens

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Copy files to another branch

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - better-page
    workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
    contents: write
    pages: write
    id-token: write

concurrency:
    group: "pages"
    cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
    copy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout better-page
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
              with:
                  ref: better-page

            - name: Copy files 1
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin better-page:better-page --update-head-ok
                  # rsync -r --exclude=.git --exclude=.github --exclude=about-me --exclude=node_modules --exclude=simplified . simplified/
                  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'simplified' -exec cp -r {} simplified \;
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "create simplified directory"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin better-page # push to remote branch

            - name: Checkout gh-pages
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
              with:
                  ref: gh-pages
                  path: gh-pages

            - name: Copy files 2
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages --update-head-ok
                  git archive --format tar better-page simplified | tar x -vf -
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "copy files from better-page"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin gh-pages # push to remote branch
```

It's meant to copy files into a folder, and then "checkout" folder into another branch, so basically copying files between branches. But when the script runs, it finishes successfully without any errors, however no commits were made in either branches.

I copied most of the code from StackOverflow, so I'm confused on what's not working.

EDIT: Some warnings it showed:

```bash
Annotations
2 warnings
copy
Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: actions/checkout@v2. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.
copy
The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

And the logs:

```
succeeded 2 hours ago in 9s
Search logs
1s
Current runner version: '2.303.0'
Operating System
Runner Image
Runner Image Provisioner
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
Secret source: Actions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v2' (SHA:ee0669bd1cc54295c223e0bb666b733df41de1c5)
Complete job name: copy
2s
Run actions/checkout@v2
Syncing repository: quincynyan/quincynyan
Getting Git version info
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/c8b9627a-19c0-4ab3-99f7-115b756d1c6d' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/quincynyan/quincynyan
Deleting the contents of '/home/runner/work/quincynyan/quincynyan'
Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
Checking out the ref
/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
'bf3cdc18f11643fb9a03e2a6eb5e2135db12cfc1'
1s
Run git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
[better-page 1908b12] create simplified directory
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/1)        
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)        
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.        
To https://github.com/quincynyan/quincynyan
   bf3cdc1..1908b12  better-page -> better-page
0s
Run actions/checkout@v2
Syncing repository: quincynyan/quincynyan
Getting Git version info
Copying '/home/runner/.gitconfig' to '/home/runner/work/_temp/8e9a2c66-c9d9-4090-9087-a01df1ad8673/.gitconfig'
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/8e9a2c66-c9d9-4090-9087-a01df1ad8673' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/quincynyan/quincynyan/gh-pages
Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
Checking out the ref
/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
'fed1db795cff8ccbaa364f6121a6f7f6883f0b7e'
0s
Run git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
From https://github.com/quincynyan/quincynyan
 * [new branch]      gh-pages   -> gh-pages
 * [new branch]      gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages
simplified/
warning: adding embedded git repository: gh-pages
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> gh-pages
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached gh-pages
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
[better-page 33fc0c8] copy files from better-page
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 160000 gh-pages
Everything up-to-date
0s
Post job cleanup.
/usr/bin/git version
git version 2.40.0
Copying '/home/runner/.gitconfig' to '/home/runner/work/_temp/cb46980b-3cf9-44eb-8849-acc56b031201/.gitconfig'
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/cb46980b-3cf9-44eb-8849-acc56b031201' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/quincynyan/quincynyan/gh-pages
/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
http.https://github.com/.extraheader
/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :"
0s
Post job cleanup.
/usr/bin/git version
git version 2.40.0
Copying '/home/runner/.gitconfig' to '/home/runner/work/_temp/794b3a8d-22e2-4378-97b6-583b0ae59af0/.gitconfig'
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/794b3a8d-22e2-4378-97b6-583b0ae59af0' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/quincynyan/quincynyan
/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'gh-pages' in .gitmodules
Warning: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
0s
Cleaning up orphan processes
```

Comment: Nothing in the logs too?

Comment: `fatal: No url found for submodule path 'gh-pages' in .gitmodules` and then `Warning: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128`. Looks like it's related to your earlier questions.

Comment: Two subsequent checkouts. Is that intentional? The second one would be nested into the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the nodejs 12 warning, nodejs 12 is deprecated so the actions received new version with nodejs 16 or newers ([see news](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/)). To make this go away, simply use version 3 of checkout: `actions/checkout@v3`.

Now, back to the error: `fatal: No url found for submodule path 'gh-pages' in .gitmodules` was caused by you trying to add 'gh-pages' git checkout into 'better-page'.

Try appending `working-directory: gh-pages` keyword to "Copy files 2" step. See more about working-directory in [GH docs on jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun)

Note that using actions/checkout with 'path' flag will not change directory that specified path (i.e. specifying gh-pages path keeps you in the same working directory). Hence "Copy files 2" step is running git commands in the same directory as before (better-page), adding a new directory 'gh-pages' which is a git checkout.

---

Here is an example of workflow that you could play and see the behavior of the runner:

```yaml
name: Test

on: [push, pull_request, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - run: git branch   # gives 'main' branch
      - run: ls   # just files in 'main'. README, etc.
      
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: other-branch
          path: other-branch
        
      # Let's check the previous commands after the checkout
      - run: git branch   # we are still in 'main'
      - run: ls   # see the new 'other-branch' directory
      
      # Let's try different stuff
      
      # Run git branch, changing to 'other-branch' directory
      - run: git -C other-branch branch
      
      # Run ls, but first set working directory to other-branch
      - run: ls 
        working-directory: other-branch
      
      # Same as above
      - run: ls other-branch
```